# C# WPF XMLReader and XMLWriter System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, ioexception, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I have 2 buttons in a WPF.

The first one writes information into an XML
The second one restores it into a List

Write Function:

```
public static void Write(List<string> numbers) {

    XmlWriterSettings myWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    myWriterSettings.CloseOutput = true;
    myWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    using (XmlWriter myWriter = XmlWriter.Create(XMLPathRestore, myWriterSettings)) {

        myWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        myWriter.WriteStartElement("Something");

        //Writing numbers into XML

        myWriter.WriteEndElement();
        myWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        myWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Read Function:

```
public static List<string> Read() {

    List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

    XmlReaderSettings myReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    myReaderSettings.CloseInput = true;

    if (File.Exists(XMLPath) == true) {
        XmlReader myReader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath, myReaderSettings);
        while (myReader.Read()) {
            //Fill List<string> numbers from XML
        }
    }
    return concernNumbers;
}
```

When i now alternately read and write after a few times i will get an System.IO.IOException which tells me that the process can not access the XML File because it is used by another process.

I thought i can handle this by setting CloseInput to true on the writer and the reader but it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: do you open the XML file somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `using`-block on the writer that should automatically close the `XmlWriter` when the block is left. Adding a using block to the reading code should work

```
using (XmlReader myReader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath, myReaderSettings))
{
  while (myReader.Read()) {
    //Fill List<string> numbers from XML
  }
}
```

Generally it's good practice to use classes that implement `IDisposable` with `using` to make sure, that `Dispose` is called and all resources are cleaned up.

Please see [the documentation on using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Answer (score 1):

close your reader after finished reading:

```
myReader.Close();
```

Comment: I was going to say that you could even do myReader.Dispose(), since XmlReader implements the IDisposable interface. That should be the proper way to be sure that you dispose all the resources used by the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath, myReaderSettings)
{
    while (myReader.Read()) {

    }
}
```

the using block will dispose each reader instance when it completed, I advice you to use `using block`